# Dynamically add HTML element with new id to a Backbone View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a template with a list `<ul>` that has 2 `<li>` with links `<a id='variable_id'>` with different ids. I've bind the events to this 2 ids `iniciais` and `palavras`. The thing is, when i click for an example the `iniciais` link, i remove it from the `<ul>` and create a new link with the `id='palavras'`. The problem is, this new link doesn't have the events binded to it, even though the event is on the `events` hash. How can i do something like `jQuery` `live` or `on` methods on a `Backbone` `View` subelement?

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#campos',
  initialize: function() {
  },
```

Notice how i have the events binded to the 2 kinds of links.

```
  events: {
    'click #palavras': 'mudar_para_consulta_palavras',
    'click #iniciais': 'mudar_para_consulta_iniciais'
  },
```

In this method, i remove the list item from the list, and insert some new content with the new id.

```
  mudar_para_consulta_palavras: function() {
    $('#campo_consulta').val('');
    $('#campo_consulta').attr('placeholder', 'Digite palavras inteiras');
    $("#campo_consulta").attr('tipo', 'chave');
    $('#palavras').parent().remove();
    $("<li><a id='#iniciais'>Consultar por Iniciais</a></li>").insertBefore('.divider');
  },
```

Same thing for this other method, only changes the id definition.

```
  mudar_para_consulta_iniciais: function() {
    $('#campo_consulta').val('');
    $('#campo_consulta').attr('placeholder', 'Digite inicio de palavras');
    $("#campo_consulta").attr('tipo', 'iniciais');
    $('#iniciais').parent().remove();
    $("<li><a id='#palavras'>Consultar por palavras</a></li>").insertBefore('.divider');
  }
});
return MyView;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply have small typo in the markup you insert into the DOM:

```
$("<li><a id='#iniciais'>Consultar por Iniciais</a></li>")
```

and

```
$("<li><a id='#palavras'>Consultar por palavras</a></li>")
```

Should not have the `#` character in the id attribute.

Comment: Omg, that is just plain stupid of me. Thanks for saving me tons of research.